# How to Log Http Communication Errors in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript

My .Net MVC application is attempting a an Http `put` call to update an existing record. I have noticed the controller `put` logic is not being triggered like other http communications.

I would like to include the HandleError logic found on [Angular's Communication Page](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) to write out the errors. When I include the error handler in my data service layer I get `Argument of type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Record>) => ObservableInput<any>'`

From what I see on  I have the correct JSON object and API url. The controller can be reached if I copy the JSON object and URL into Postman.

Any insight provided on error handling and logging would be greatly appreciated.

Component logic:

```
updateRecord(record_id: number, newRecord: any): void
{
   this.recordService.put<Record>(record_id, newRecord);
}
```

Data service logic:

```
put<Record>(record_id: number, record: Record): Observable<Record> {
    var url = this.baseUrl + `api/record/${record_id}`;
    let output = this.http.put<Record>(url, record, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('put<Record>', record))
    );

    return output;
 }
```

Handle Error:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        consol e.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
        console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
    return throwError(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Controller logic:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Domain.Record>> Put(int id, [FromBody] Domain.Record record)
{
    //Confirm the request record and ID record being update match
    if (id != record.record_id)
        return BadRequest();

    //Modify the state
    _context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
    //Update the records in DB.records, throw appropriate error if there is one.
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!RecordExists(record.record_id))
            return NotFound();
        else
            throw;
    }

    //return 200 OK
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: The issue probably lies in your `handleError()` function. Can you add that as well?

Comment: It is not obvious to me where `never` or Observable<never>` is defined or what that error refers to; nor if you ever subscribe to the results from your data service `put` method.

Comment: @JeffryHouser you got me set in the right direction. I had not subscribed to the call on the component. Do you mind answering this with a quick blurb about why subscribe matters? I will mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were missing a subscribe somewhere, per the comments on the main question.

In RXJS an Observable that is not subscribed to will never execute.  So, this:

```
updateRecord(record_id: number, newRecord: any): void
{
   this.recordService.put<Record>(record_id, newRecord);
}
```

Should be turned into this:

```
updateRecord(record_id: number, newRecord: any): void
{
   this.recordService.put<Record>(record_id, newRecord).subscribe((result) => {
    // process results here
   };
}
```

Without the subscribe, I do not believe you'll get any results from the HTTP call inside that `recordService.put()` from.